# Как работает photoshop API?

Tags: api, azure, photoshop

Всем привет. Кто знает как работать вот с   [этим](https://www.adobe.io/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/api/#operation/photoshopActions) ? Я понимаю логику работы команды так: есть картинка, которая где то хранится, к ней применяется экшен, который так же где то хранится удаленно, а в **presigned-url** помещается результат запроса. Главная моя проблема, в том что я не совсем понимаю, как работают presigned-url, как ее сделать с помощью *Dropbox* или *SAS* в *Azure* ?